# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'javabridge._javabridge'

Tags: python

I am on Debian 11, Python 3.9.7

I have installed java OpenJDK 11 (Current version I think is 17, but for some software I need 11)

```
(base) ~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /home/daniel/jdk-11.0.15+10/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

The java version:

```
(base) ~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10, mixed mode)
```

Also defined JAVA_HOME:

```
(base) daniel@tuxysbu:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

I have installed Anaconda, pip install javabridge, pip install python-bioformats

However, when I try to import javabridge, I got the following error:
import javabridge

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_227911/3278431438.py", line 1, in <module>
    import javabridge

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/javabridge/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .jutil import start_vm, kill_vm, vm, activate_awt, deactivate_awt

  File "/home/daniel/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/javabridge/jutil.py", line 157, in <module>
    import javabridge._javabridge as _javabridge

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'javabridge._javabridge'
```

If anyone has an idea why this problem, please, let me know

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a problem with java/javac
Better re-install it.
Try:

```
pip uninstall javabridge
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jdk
pip install javabridge
```

This should fix it

Comment: I had both installed, but it looks re-installing at the same time fixed the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the IDE you are using is in the correct anaconda environment. I had a similar problem once and all I did was change my anaconda environment in visual studio code(the IDE I use).